# PHP sort mysql objects by time

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, date, time

So I have this php code:

```
"SELECT * FROM thread_db ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
```

This echos me later the last 3 rows of my mysql database. I somehow need it to get sorted by time so I get the 3 latest entries by time (closest to current date).

Comment: Do you have a time field in your table? Order by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
"SELECT * FROM thread_db ORDER BY your_time_field DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Replace `your_time_field` with the exact name of your time column in the query